# How to get computer brand and model in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an web application to retrieve the computers brand and model... Can anyone guide me up in the right direction?
I already search google, but find few things about it.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can probably get more reliable answers by simply asking the user.

Comment: Is it even possible to do this on a desktop app?  You can get identifying information for the parts, but brand and model isn't likely to exist in any easily obtainable format

Comment: The closest thing I can find is to use System.getProperties(), but that still at best involves having to figure out what the keys are, which I highly doubt is doable in a cross-platform way.

Comment: The best you'll be able to do is look at the user agent, which is trivially spoofable.

Comment: @DennisMeng - don't think that an untrusted applet can read the system properties.  Besides, the computer manufacturer and model won't be in there ... unless the user has somehow tweaked the JVM to put them there.

Comment: @DaveNewton - have you ever seen the computer manufacturer / model in a user agent string?

Comment: Is this a webapp, applet, or desktop app?

Comment: I don't think you'll ever get this answer. In many cases it's not possible to determine the brand and model by physically looking at the computer. In some cases there isn't a brand and model (generic motherboard stuffed in a generic case).

Comment: @StephenC That makes sense. (I wasn't actually sure if System.getProperties() would actually work anyway, it was more of a "if there's a way to do it, i'd suspect it'd probably involve this..." type of comment)

Comment: @StephenC Nope--but there's information in there that will get you as close as you can get. That's why I said "the best you can do", instead of "this will tell you". Perhaps I was unclear.

Comment: *"Can anyone guide me up in the right direction?"*  The best direction would be had by describing the goal, as opposed to the task.  The goal can best be expressed by answering this question.  What feature do you intend to offer to the user?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are barking up the wrong tree here ...

In a properly implemented web browser, any executable code from the webapp will be run in a security sandbox that (among other things) prevents it from accessing potentially sensitive on the user's computer.  The computer's brand and model is potentially sensitive.

Even if you get past that (e.g. by convincing the user to install a trusted browser plugin or applet), you've then got the problem that there is no cross-platform way to determine the make and model of the user's computer.  Different OS'es handle this in different ways, and it may require administrator / root privilege to get this information.

**Update**

As of 2020 you have even more impediments to developing a solution to this problem in Java:

- Mainstream browsers no longer support Java and have not done for a few years.  An Icedtea plugin is an option for some browsers / operating systems, but Icedtea has not progressed past Java 8.
- Java 9+ has largely removed support for applets and Java webstart from Oracle Java.

---

> Can anyone guide me up in the right direction.

Well, given that Java in the browser is dead technology, the right direction is likely to be one of the following:

- Reimplement your application as a stand-alone Java application.  This renders the problem moot.
- Change your application so that it doesn't need to know what the user's hardware platform is.

(You never said why you are doing this, and I am having difficulty imagining a sound reason for needing this kind of information.)